# How to use writeStringArray() and readStringArray() in a Parcel

Tags: java, android, marshalling, parcelable, parcel

I recently came across a very stupid (at least from my point of view) implementation inside Androids `Parcel` class.

Suppose I have a simple class like this

```
class Foo implements Parcelable{

    private String[] bars;
    //other members

    public in describeContents(){ 
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags){

        dest.writeStringArray(bars);
        //parcel others
    }

    private Foo(Parcel source){
        source.readStringArray(bars);
        //unparcel other members
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Foo> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Foo>(){

         public Foo createFromParcel(Parcel source){
             return new Foo(source);
         }

         public Foo[] newArray(int size){
             return new Foo[size];
         }

    };
}
```

Now, if I want to Parcel a `Foo` Object and `bars` is null I see no way to recover from this situation (exept of catching Exceptions of course). Here is the implementation of these two methods from Parcel:

```
 public final void writeStringArray(String[] val) {
        if (val != null) {
            int N = val.length;
            writeInt(N);
            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                writeString(val[i]);
            }
        } else {
            writeInt(-1);
        }
    }


  public final void readStringArray(String[] val) {
        int N = readInt();
        if (N == val.length) {
            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                val[i] = readString();
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("bad array lengths");
        }
    }
```

So writeStringArray is fine if I pass `bars` which are null. It just writes `-1` to the Parcel. But How is the method readStringArray supposed to get used? If I pass `bars` inside (which of course is null) I will get a NullPointerException from `val.length`. If I create `bars` before like say `bars = new String[???]` I don't get any clue how big it should be. If the size doesn't match what was written inside I recieve a RuntimeException.

Why is `readStringArray` not aware of a result of `-1` which gets written on null objects from `writeStringArray` and just returns?

The only way I see is to save the size of `bars` before I call `writeStringArray(String[])` which makes this method kind of useless. It will also redundatly save the size of the Array twice (one time for me to remember, the second time from `writeStringArray`).

Does anyone know how these two methods are supposed to be used, as there is NO java-doc for them on top?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should use [`Parcel.createStringArray()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#createStringArray%28%29) in your case.

I can't imagine a proper use-case for [`Parcel.readStringArray(String[] val)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readStringArray%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) but in order to use it you have to know the exact size of array and manually allocate it.

Comment: thanks. never notices these create* functions. I'll still leave this question open a bit, so that someone could give me a purpose for that ugly method.

Answer (score 5):

It's not really clear from the (lack of) documentation but `readStringArray()` is to be used when the object already knows how to create the string array before calling this function; for example when it's statistically instanciated or it's size is known from another previously read value.

What you need here is to call the function `createStringArray()` instead.