# Parcleable extra not there after starting activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

I am trying to implement Parcleable so that I can add it as an extra (this is a requirement).

Here is a slimmed down version of the class `SwinImage` which only shows relevant details, namely the parts which are derived from Parcleable:

```
package com.example.kevin.imagemetadata;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class SwinImage implements Parcelable
{
    public SwinImage(String imageName, String location, String[] keywords, String imageDate, boolean share, String email, int rating)
    {
        update(imageName, location, keywords, imageDate, share, email, rating);
    }

    //A constructor for when we havent assigned any metadata.
    public SwinImage(String imageName)
    {
    }

    public void update(String imageName, String location, String[] keywords, String imageDate, boolean share, String email, int rating)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
    }

    private void storeImageDetails() {
    }

    @Override
    //We don't need it - but we are forced to due to interface.
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
    {
        out.writeString(imageName);
        out.writeString(location);

        out.writeStringArray(keywords);

        out.writeString(imageDate);

        //Can write boolean array but not boolean...
        boolean[] temp = {share};

        out.writeBooleanArray(temp);
        out.writeString(email);

        out.writeInt(rating);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SwinImage> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SwinImage>()
    {

        @Override
        public SwinImage createFromParcel(Parcel parcel)
        {
            return new SwinImage(parcel);
        }

        @Override
        public SwinImage[] newArray(int i)
        {
            return new SwinImage[i];
        }
    };

    //THE PRIVATE CONSTRUCTOR - FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY.
    private SwinImage(Parcel parcel)
    {
        imageName = parcel.readString();
        location = parcel.readString();

        parcel.readStringArray(keywords);

        imageDate = parcel.readString();

        boolean[] tempArr = new boolean[1];
        parcel.readBooleanArray(tempArr);
        share = tempArr[0];

        email = parcel.readString();
        rating = parcel.readInt();
    }

}
```

Ok... So, in the calling class, I do this:

```
public void ClickedImage(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MetaDataActivity.class);

    switch (getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId()))
    {
        case "burgerView":
            i.putExtra("SENT_IMAGE", burger); //IT IMPLEMENTS PARCLEABLE THEREFORE WE CAN PASS IT WHERE IT LOOKS FOR A PARCEL
            break;
        case "pitaView":
            i.putExtra("SENT_IMAGE", pita);
            break;
        case "pizzaView":
            i.putExtra("SENT_IMAGE", pizza);
            break;
        case "steakView":
            i.putExtra("SENT_IMAGE", steak);
            break;
    }

    startActivityForResult(i, GET_AND_SET_METADATA_REQUEST);
}
```

I set a breakpoint at the end, and can indeed see that it is in the intent correctly:

[The Intent showing an Extra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7XiP.png)

However, when it comes to getting it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.d("Does", "Does this work");

    Intent i;
    i = getIntent();
    image = i.getExtras().getParcelable("SENT_IMAGE");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_meta_data);
}
```

It is never there. The assignment to `image` crashes the program, and I cannot see through the debugger my `SwinImage` even existing inside the intent.

What am I doing wrong? Why is it crashing? I have tried for hours solutions (mainly changing how I'm assigning - and some "solutions" have stopped it from crashing, but `image` is assigned a null)

Can anyone provide some insight? Thanks.

Edit:

I tried moving the `getIntent` to after `onCreate` to no avail.

Edit #2: Stack trace:

http://pastebin.com/raw/XJbPxHRv

and types of `steak` etc:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int GET_AND_SET_METADATA_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code
    SwinImage burger, pita, pizza, steak;
```

Comment: If you've got a crash, why not to attach crash log from device's logcat? Also show types of variables that your code uses (`image`, `pizza`, etc.).

Comment: Hi, Thanks @Serhio I've updated the OP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't call `getIntent()` before `super.onCreate()` - no Intent is available at that point.

Move your `super` call before the `getIntent` call.

**UPDATE:**

After the above fix, your stack trace shows the issue:

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at android.os.Parcel.readStringArray(Parcel.java:1026)
at com.example.kevin.imagemetadata.SwinImage.<init>(SwinImage.java:108)
```

It seems `keywords` is `null`, so attempting to read it from the parcel crashes.
Either make sure `keywords` is never null, or put a boolean that says if keywords can be read or not.
Also, per this: [How to use writeStringArray() and readStringArray() in a Parcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385253/how-to-use-writestringarray-and-readstringarray-in-a-parcel) you should probably use createStringArray instead of readStringArray, a lot simpler.

A general note: you should always read your crashes stack traces carefully to better understand why your code isn't working as expected, usually it's the best way to fix broken code.

Comment: It is not true. `getIntent()` is valid even before `super.onCreate()`. `Activity`'s intent is initialized before dispatching of `onCreate()` callback. Generally it is done via `Activity.attach()`. See [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e2d281/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2159) for details.

Comment: Hi, I moved it to after the `super.onCreate()` and it still crashes :(

Comment: post your stack trace, either intent or getExtras are null.

Comment: Thanks @marmor I have updated the OP with the stack trace.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! It solved my problem, I did upvote but it wont be displayed until I reach 15 reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `SwinImage` constructor that takes a `Parcel` as argument, you do this:

```
parcel.readStringArray(keywords);
```

This fails because it attempts to read an array of `String` into `keywords`, which is `null` because you did not initialize it first.

When you call `readStringArray()`, you pass it a reference to an existing array of `String`, into which it will copy the array of `String` from the `Parcel`.

Note the `readStringArray()` and `writeStringArray()` will only work correctly if the array reference that you pass to `writeStringArray()` is not `null` and if the number of elements in the array you pass to `readStringArray()` is exactly the same as the number of elements that you have in the array you pass to `writeStringArray()`.

Instead of `readStringArray()` you should probably use `createStringArray()` which doesn't have these restrictions. Use it like this:

```
keywords = parcel.createStringArray();
```